# Support multiple authentication methods with ASP.NET core with Web and Windows Clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am trying to develop a concept to support multiple authentication methods in an ASP.NET core server environment which should support both Windows (WPF) clients as well as Web clients (Angular). Users should be able to login using three methods:

1. using username & password, which is checked against database of valid logins
2. using Windows authentication (i.e. the currently logged in user). This may require user PC and server to be on the same network/domain
3. using selected external authentication providers, such as Google

Users should have individual rights (claims), which either derive from their individual profile or group membership (e.g. in case of AD).

I am still at the concept phase, trying to figure out the basics here, so no code has been written yet.

My thinking is as follows:

1. users logging in using username & password receive a token (JWT) of some sort which then authorizes them to access protected/restricted calls.
2. users logging in using their Windows identity would basically receive the same token
3. users logging in via external auth-providers would receive the external token from the provider and use that to login and also receive an token from the server
4. regardless of 1-3, users end up with a server-issued token that gives them access to restricted features

Is that a common/correct approach for mixed authentication? If so, how would this be implemented on the ASP.NET core server side?

Comment: Your best bet would be to go with IdentityServer4 it has openid and also will allow to connect directly supplying username and password if you don't want to redirect user to browser first, not sure about the windows identity though

Comment: the concept you want to research is probably "federated identity"